# Does the implementation of GPPSignInDelegate have to be a ViewController or AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, google-plus

I'm trying to integrate an iOS application that I'm writing in Swift with Google Plus following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started). After getting it all to work within a `ViewController` I foolishly thought I could encapsulate the authentication behaviour inside its own class (below)

The problem is that the two `GPPSignInDelegate` protocol functions `finishedwithAuth` and `didDisconnectWithError` never get called. If I pass in a `ViewController` or the `AppDelegate` that implements `GPPSignInDelegate` and assign it to the `googlePlus.delegate` the callbacks are called successfully; when I assign `self` to the delegate the callbacks are never called.

```
import Foundation


class GoogleAuthentication : GPPSignInDelegate  {

  let kClientId: NSString = ""
  let googlePlus: GPPSignIn
  var authenticatedSuccessfully: Bool?

  // Passing in a ViewController implementing GPPSignInDelegate works
  // init(delegate: GPPSignInDelegate) {    
  init() {
      self.delegate = delegate
      googlePlus = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
      googlePlus.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true
      googlePlus.clientID = kClientId
      googlePlus.scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin]
      googlePlus.delegate = self // works when assignging delegate passed in

      authenticatedSuccessfully = googlePlus.trySilentAuthentication()
  }

  func authenticate() {
      googlePlus.authenticate()
  }

  func finishedWithAuth(auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication!, error: NSError!) {
      println("finished with auth!")
  }

  func didDisconnectWithError(error: NSError!) {
      println("disconnected with error!")
  }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing or does the `GPPSignInDelegate` have to be implemented by a `ViewController` or the `AppDelegate`? And if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate object has to inherit from NSObject. So it becomes:

```
class GoogleAuthentication: NSObject, GPPSignInDelegate  {
```

Comment: My class inherits from NSObject and conforms to the GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate protocols but it still doesn't work